# Supervisor is not available. Cannot install it on a fresh Debian 9.13

Tags: debian, python, package-management, supervisord

On our vagrant **dev** environment, when provisioning (Vagrant box debian 9.13) I install Supervisor using shell provisioner. Always working as expected. That's the content of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install supervisor=3.*

cp /home/vagrant/projectX/vagrant/configs/supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor

chmod 777 -R /etc/supervisor/conf.d
```

A few days ago, it turns out that Supervisor is not being installed anymore when provisioning.

The error we get is:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Selected version '3.3.5-1' (Debian:10.10/oldstable [all]) for 'supervisor'
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> supervisor : Depends: python-meld3 but it is not installable
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Also, trying to install manually using:
(Supervisor 4.* is not using python-meld3, that's why tried)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install supervisor -y
```

I got:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Package supervisor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source
> E: Package 'supervisor' has no installation candidate

Things I have tried:

### Installing python-meld3:

```
sudo apt-get install python-meld3 -y
```

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Package python-meld3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source
> E: Package 'python-meld3' has no installation candidate

```
apt-cache policy python-meld3

python-meld3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
     1.0.2-2 -10
        -10 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        -10 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
```

Also by downloading the code from [meld3 Github](https://github.com/Supervisor/meld3) and installing by hand with same result.

### Fix dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
> sgml-base xml-core
> Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Nothing supervisor related.

### Add repos to sources.list

From here: [Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296488/e-package-any-package-has-no-installation-candidate)

```
apt-cache policy supervisor
```

Shows:

> supervisor:
> Installed: (none)
> Candidate: (none)
> Version table:
>
> > ```
> > 3.3.5-1 -10
> > ```
> >
> > > ```
> > >    -10 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
> > > ```
> >
> > ```
> > 3.3.1-1+deb9u1 -10
> > ```
> >
> > > ```
> > >    -10 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
> > >    -10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
> > > ```

Then added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo apt-get update` and all of them are ignored...

UPDATE: Current sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
```

What is happening? What I'm missing? It's being quite difficult to install it. Any help would be really appreciated!

PD: I cannot upgrade to Debian 10 or 11. We are fixed to 9.13

Comment: If you're fixed to 9.13, then why do you have Debian 10 repositories configured in your sources.list?

Comment: Hi! which ones are you referring to? Thanks!

Comment: Rather than investigating about _supervisor_ 3.x (which is clearly available) you should investigate _python-meld3_, which is missing when it should be available. // `apt-cache policy` shows you have Debian 10 (buster) APT sources somewhere.

Comment: I'm referring to the ones that say `buster` in your "apt-cache policy" output. Debian Buster is Debian 10. If the main sources.list file doesn't reference it, then something in the `sources.list.d/` directory probably does.

Comment: You guys are right. We have "buster.list" in "sources.list.d/". Also what I mean by fixed is we cannot upgrade to Debian 10.  @DanielB I have also tried to install python-meld3 (as posted) without no success, If it is available, why there is "no candidate"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, by removing the sources from `buster.list` it started to work again.